# Stop Visual Studio 2010 from auto removing files from solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a big solution (50+ projects, mixed C++, C++/CLI, C#) plus a number of support files (many are python files) in solution folders. From time to time, for no apparent reasons, Visual Studio removes references to one or more python file from the solution. It's easy to revert via the version control system, but gets annoying over time if you have to do this several times a week.

Anyone knows how to prevent Visual Studio from doing this?

Comment: You'll need to turn on diagnostic logging, as Visual Studio isn't removing them for fun...it will have a reason.  Start it with /log at the end.

Comment: /log does nothing, do you mean the system.diagnostics setting in devenv.exe.config?

Comment: mmm, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms241272.aspx suggests it should do something.  But devenv.exe.config is a different way to achieve the same thing...so which ever is easiest for you.

Comment: I have the same problem with .md files. Apparently the files get removed when opened and closed, possibly while being read from an external program.